# Get facebook Album URL using php-sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the facebook php-sdk, users can upload photos to facebook from our site. I can create the album and upload the photos. But **can't get the URL to the newly created Album** :(

Here's what I do ...

```
// create album
$albumDetails = array(
  'name' => 'Fun images'
);
$album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $albumDetails);
$albumID = $album['id'];

// upload photos
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $file = FACEBOOK_IMAGES_DIR . $image->image_id . '.jpg';
    $photoDetails = array(
         'message'=> 'by choreboy'
    );
    $photoDetails['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);
    $photoData = $facebook->api('/'.$albumID.'/photos', 'post', $photoDetails);  
}
// Graph API says I can get link to the album:
// http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album
// I thought I could get to the link data this way. But returns an empty array
$data=$facebook->api("/{$albumID}/photos?access_token={$session['access_token']}");
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: did the photo get to facebook and posted as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the first line in [this code.](http://daipratt.co.uk/facebook-api-upload-photo/)

Answer (score 0):

This URL redirects to your album:

```
$album_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/' . $albumID;
```